# Django receiving duplicate signals when updating content from HTML page

Tags: django

I am getting duplicate of each content when updating content from html page. see the picture:
[image]

I am not getting any duplicate when updating from Django admin panel. How to avoid duplicate when updating from HTML template?

here is my code

I think I am doing any mistake in my views. here is my **views.py**

```
class ApproveCommentPage(UpdateView):
      model = BlogComment
      template_name = "blog/approve_comment.html"
      form_class =AdminComment
     
      def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        status = self.object.is_published
        name = self.object.name[0:20]
        messages.success(self.request, f"{name} comment status {status}")
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

#Updating question

here is my notifications.html where rendering all messages:

**notifications.html**

```
{% for notification in  notifications  %} 
{%if user.id ==   notification.blog.author.id %}
{% if notification.notification_type == "Comment Approved" %}

 {{ notification.text_preview }}
            
{%endif%}
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

**notification.views.py**

```
def ShowNOtifications(request):
    notifications = Notifications.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    
    template_name ='blog/notifications.html'
     
   

    context = {
        'notifications': notifications,
    }
    print("##############",context)      
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

my html page where I am updating comment status. By default all comment status "pending" which means unpublished. here I am reviewing every comment and changing their status to "published". Only getting duplicate when changing status from here.
**approve_commnet.html**

```
<form  method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
             
            
            <button class="btn btn-info">Publish</button>
        </form>
```

When updating comment status from admin panel I am not getting any duplicate. Only getting duplicate When trying to update comment status from approve_commnet.html .

Comment: Can you share the part of the template where you *render* the messages?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I updated my question and describe details. Please see

Comment: but where do you render the *messages* (not the form), but the messages on your page?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am rendering message in notifications.html. please see above I marked bold   notifications.html.

Comment: But you here use Django's messages framework, but you render it with a `Notification`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `def form_valid(self, form):` method you save your object as `self.object = form.save()` and when your logic is done you return `super().form_valid(form)` which actually saves the instance again so you got a duplicate. In my opinion , the best solution is that do not save the object in your method let the `super().form_valid()` save it for you. Second one, instead of `return super().form_valid(form)` , `return super(FormMixin).form_valid(form)`

Edited:
I think the best solution is;

```
class ApproveCommentPage(UpdateView):
    model = BlogComment
    template_name = "blog/approve_comment.html"
    form_class = AdminComment # Assumed this is a ModelForm
     
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False) # this kwarg makes save method not to save it to database.
        status = self.object.is_published
        name = self.object.name[0:20]
        messages.success(self.request, f"{name} comment status {status}")
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: berkeeb Thanks for your answare. Can you please little bit edit your answer and tell me where I need to be edited in my views.py